# Valid user processes in Windows XP

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-xp, ps

I was doing a lab to remotely list processes running on a VM Windows XP machine. I was able to run the command, but forgot to take a screenshot. After that I logged in as another user and kicked out the old user logged in.

Now there is a question asking what 3 processes were running under that user.

I was able to answer 2 correctly but can't determine 1 more. The processes are :

1.msmsgs.exe (I chose this correctly as a process running under that user)

2.smss.exe  (Not sure - it seems this can ONLY belong to a system)

3.logon.scr (My guess as the last choice)

4.winlogon.exe (Not sure - it seems this can ONLY belong to a system)

5.svchost.exe (Not sure - it seems this can ONLY belong to a system)

6.explorer.exe (I chose correctly as a process running under that user)

Please help choose the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smss.exe and winlogon.exe will never run as anything other than SYSTEM unless there is a virus on the machine. svchost.exe will not normally run as a normal user but it could in theory if a service is configured that way.

So yes, it is most likely that logon.scr (a screen saver) is the 3rd user process.